# Should a responsive website have the same breakpoints for every page or can they be different for each page?

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, mobile-web

I'm designing a responsive e-commerce website. I'm wondering if every page of the site should have the exact same breakpoints or not. Since pages like Product detail page, account page, shopping cart page would have feature or elements that may fit or look poorly on different screen sizes. Should I design those element and feature sizes based on the breakpoints that I have chosen for the website? Or should I design each page individually and come up with their individual breakpoints afterwards?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

**Ideally, you'd design your break points to happen only when they need to, based on your specific content.** This is developing with a user-first kind of mentality: everything you do is geared towards providing the best, most highly-optimized experience for the user, no matter what.

This, however, takes a bit more care and development time. Also, it's not as easily maintained. If next month, you have to add another tab to your navigation, well now it might not fit very well on your medium screen size, so you'd have to adjust your break point or change your CSS just to handle that additional tab.

If you're okay with compromising slightly to gain several benefits, then **using static breakpoints (like what you'll likely find already baked in to a grid framework) reduces development costs and allows you to develop more maintainable code.** By sticking to static break points, you can more easily predict how things will lay out while developing. This leads to more rapid code production, with more predictable testing. The compromise here is that perhaps a couple pages are not as "custom-fit" to any given screen size without additional work.

<sub>(Personally, I opt for the latter, and special case only certain things that don't fit well within the predefined ranges.)</sub>